# activate 2 Edge windows with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple script which automatically cycles tabs on 2 different edge windows, I have it working on one window in the code below

```
while(1 -eq 1){
    $wshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
    $wshell.AppActivate('Edge'); # Activate on Edge browser
    Sleep 5; # Interval (in seconds) between switch 
    $wshell.SendKeys('^{PGUP}'); # Ctrl + Page Up keyboard shortcut to switch tab
}
```

How could I activate the second Edge window?

I have already tried alt-tab ing to the other one with this
`$wshell.SendKeys('%{TAB}');`
but it didnt seem to work

Comment: I can see that Alt-Tab doesn't work reliably. It seems that the very same `msedge.exe` process hosts _all_ windows and selectively hides and shows them, so you can't even target via PIDs (process IDs). Note that GUI scripting is inherently unreliable. I have no personal experience with it, but perhaps [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is a robust alternative; the third-party [Selenium PowerShell Module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) is a PowerShell wrapper for it, but I don't know if it still works (the project is looking for maintainers).